# Python-- How to calculate the total of inputs from "while" or "for loop"?

Tags: python

Use for/while loop to take user input to calculate the total which display as below:

```
    Welcome to the receipt program:      
    Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: 12   
    Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: 15.50
    Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: 9.98   
    Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: 14.05    
    Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: q               
    Total:$51.53    
    Enter the value for the seat ['q' to quit]: five   
    I'm sorry, but 'five' isn't valid. Please try again.
```

---

I am able to print the input and break the loop with 'q' but failed to calculate the total

---

```
print "Welcome to receipt program!"

while true:
    receipt= raw_input('Enter the value for the seat [q to quit]:')
    if receipt == 'q':
        break
    if not receipt.isdigit():
        print "I'm sorry, but {}".format(receipt) + " isn't valid. Please try again"
    total = receipt
    print "total:{}".format(receipt)
```

Comment: You are printing `receipt` ? Change it with `total`

Comment: You are updating your `total` variable with the `receipt` that the user provided every time, which is over writing your `total` value. You may want to consider `total += receipt` and put it at the right place within your while loop so that it only keeps track of the sum if a valid input is made by user. And print the `total` at the end as @OmerTekbiyik pointed out.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger and step through your code.  You would then see that you are never adding anything to total as @Endyd explained.

Comment: By the way `receipt` is returning string .You need to convert to Int or Float what you want

Comment: If you are just learning Python now, switch to Python 3. Python 2 support is coming to an end in less than a year.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Welcome to receipt program!"

total = 0
while true:
    receipt= raw_input('Enter the value for the seat [q to quit]:')
    if receipt == 'q':
        break
    if not receipt.isdigit():
        print "I'm sorry, but {}".format(receipt) + " isn't valid. Please try again"
    else:
        total += float(receipt)

print "total:%f" % receipt
```

Comment: total += (float)receipt   
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 

I wonder what is wrong with the syntax? Thanks

Comment: float(receipt) not (float)receipt would be my guess.